# Count the fraction of trials for which the absolute deviation from the mean is larger than the standard deviation?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, mean, standard-deviation, mean-absolute-deviation

So, I have a data set containing 99 elements each with their own associated value. I have computed the standard deviation and the mean, but I am a little stumped with how exactly I should proceed with answering this.

I think that I am supposed to compute the mean absolute deviation (MAD) value using:

$D(\bar{x})= \frac{1}{N} \Sigma^{N}_{i=1} |x_i - \bar{x_i}|$

Then determine the range in which the MAD exceeds the standard deviation $\sigma$

$D + \sigma = N_{max}$

Then using the normalization condition I can determine the fraction of trials that exceeds one standard deviation.

$1 = \Sigma^{N}_{i} P(x_i)$

Now putting it all together

$1 - \Sigma^{N_{max}}_{i} P(x_i) \cdot (\text{Number of trials}) =$Fraction of trials in which the MAD is larger than a standard deviation

Does this seem like the correct way of going about this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have some value for the standard deviation, say $4$. Then you have $99$ Absolute deviations from the mean. How many of those $99$ values exceed $4?$

Comment: Well, it would depend on what the absolute deviations from the mean is, right? Because then it would just be as simple as counting each one that exceeded 4. However, the absolute deviation from the mean is a singular value, not a range of values. So either it is larger than 4 or it isn't.

Comment: The *mean* absolute deviation is one value. From your $99$ points, you get $99$ individual absolute deviations from the mean.

Comment: Maybe this is a question about the Empirical Rule, which says about "$2/3$" (some say "68%") of observations in a 'mound shaped' distribution or sample are within one SD of the mean. So about $1/3$ would be farther from the mean. // The ER (with 68.27%) is exactly true for normal distributions, approximately true for many normal samples, and surprisingly accurate for many other distributions and samples encountered in practice. // About "95%" for 2 standard deviations. //  In R, code `diff(pnorm(c(-1,1)))` returns  $0.6826895$ (for standard normal).

Comment: Hmm that is an interesting thought. However, the ER comes as something very new to me, but I'm willing to give it a shot. I use Python for data analysis, but I'm sure there's a function in. scipy or something.